# Bixby: How do I set an initial-value to self BirthdayInfo in a date-picker within a input-view?

Tags: bixby, bixbystudio

What additional steps do I need to take set the date-picker's initial-value to the user's birthday using the **viv.self** library? Is this the best place to handle this? Currently I am setting the default to 30 Years Prior.

```
render {
date-picker {
  // Default Date -30 Years (viv.self Birthday Option)
  initial-value ("subtractDuration(now().date, 'P30Y')")
  restrictions {
    // allow selection 80 Years Ago
    min-allowed ("subtractDuration(now().date, 'P80Y')")
    // to allow selection 18 Years Ago
    max-allowed ("subtractDuration(now().date, 'P18Y')")
  }
}
```

}

Comment: Which concept does the Input view match to? It would be great if you can share the entire code for Input-view. You can exclude other items in the Input-view that you don't want to share.

Comment: The concept is a structure with the role-of (time.Date)

There is not much more to the Input-view...

input-view {
  match: BirthDate (this) {
  }

  message {
    template-macro (BirthDateText)
  }

Comment: Can you provide some more the context behind this input view? What does the capsule (or this part of the capsule) do? The main question I have is: If you already have the user's birthdate via the viv.self library, what date is the user being asked for that triggers this input-view?

Comment: Ideally the end user would be select a date other than their birthday. If it's not possible, I'll just keep the date picker initial value as is.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use a `match-pattern` to achieve this.
2. Birthday is a part of the viv.contact library but is not available in the **viv.self** library.

In your Action, create an additional attribute of type `time.Date` (or a concept with `role-of` of `time.Date`) to hold the Birthday.

Heres how the code would look like.

```
action (GetBirthDate) {
  type(Constructor)
  description (Collect the date selected by a user)

  collect {

    input (usersBirthday) {
      type (BirthDate)
      min (Required) max (One)
      default-init {
        intent {
        // TO-DO Get the birthday with an intent
        }
      }
    }

    // This input will hold the value entered by the user
    computed-input (birthDate) {
      type (BirthDate)
      min (Required) max (One)
      compute {
        intent {
          goal: BirthDate
        }
      }
    }
  } output (BirthDate)
}
```

The BirthDate concept used in the code above looks like this

```
structure (BirthDate) {
  description (__DESCRIPTION__)
  role-of (time.Date)
}
```

Your input-view will look like this. This defines a `match-pattern` that is invoked whenever we need an input view for BirthDate and that BirthDate is functioning as an input back to the action.

Checkout match patterns here: https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/dev-guide/developers/customizing-plan.match-patterns

```
input-view {
  match: BirthDate (this) {
    to-input {
      GetBirthDate (action)
    }
  }


  render {
    date-picker {
      initial-value (action.usersBirthday)
      restrictions {
        // allow selection 80 Years Ago
        min-allowed ("subtractDuration(now().date, 'P80Y')")
        // to allow selection 18 Years Ago
        max-allowed ("subtractDuration(now().date, 'P18Y')")
      }
    }
  }
}
```