# Bixby NL using a integer data type

Tags: bixby, bixbystudio

How do I return an integer datatype from Bixby's NL Training? The input-view is using a slider element, the concept is set to integer,  so I believe the conversation driver/NL needs to output an integer as opposed to text/string. Using a vocabulary file obviously doesn't work in this situation.

I assume it would be similar to how the Money role outputs a float ie:

```
What can I get for {[g:viv.money.MaxPrice] ($)[v:viv.money.PrefixSymbol:$](40)[v:viv.money.CurrencyValue]}
```

Answer (score 0):

When your capsule uses primitive types, (integer in your case) it is better to create your own type that is derived from the primitives.

```
integer (MyAge) {
  description (__DESCRIPTION__)
}
```

Your NL training could be like `My age is 25` and you can tag 25 as Integer.

```
input-view {
  match: MyAge (this) {
    to-input: GetMyAge (action)
  }

  message {
    template (Testing MyAge)
  }

  render {

    form {
      // the intent that will be used when the form is submitted
      on-submit {
        goal: MyAge
        value: viv.core.FormElement(id)
      }

      elements {
        slider {
          step(1)
          id (id)
          type (viv.core.Integer)
          max-label ()
          min-value (1)
          max-value (123)
          value("#{value(action.integerValue)}")
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

action (GetMyAge) {
  type(Search)
  description (__DESCRIPTION__)

  collect {
    input (integerValue) {
      type (viv.core.Integer)
      min (Required) max (One)
      default-init {
        intent {
          goal: viv.core.Integer
          value: viv.core.Integer (1)
        }
      }
    }
    computed-input (myInteger) {
      type (viv.core.Integer)
      min (Required) max (One)
      compute {
        intent {
          goal: viv.core.Integer
        }
      }
    }
  }
  output (viv.core.Integer)
```

Try this and let us know if it worked.

Comment: So the Primitive is already set to integer. I think the problem comes down to the value returned in  NL model. For instance.. The currency value that I mentioned results in the NL training is `40.0` with no quotes.  However the primitive that is set to an integer,  has a value of `"100000"` so I think the value is being rejected by the type.

Comment: I tested this particular scenario and it works fine. I am able to set the slider to show the value that comes from the NL. 

You may want to refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54892807/bixby-how-do-i-set-an-initial-value-to-self-birthdayinfo-in-a-date-picker-withi/54954105#54954105 if you want to initialize the slider to a particular value.

Comment: I'd like to see your test if possible. I haven't been able to get this to work successfully. Initializing the slider value was a separate issue, but I was happy to have it solved.